# Moto X not receiving push notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, motorola

I'm developing an app that receives push notifications from a server using GCM, have tested it in different devices and works properly except for a Moto X, I've debugged it trying to catch the moment when the notification lands but it doesn't even try. Anyone know a reason for this?

If necessary I'll include the code for the service.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of the Moto X? Moto X Play by chance?